# multiple values combined in select helper rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, form-helpers, grouped-collection-select

This gives me a select box with only the `first_name` as the value.  I'd like to combine both the `first_name` and the `last_name` to display the full name as a value.

I'm thinking I'll have to create a variable to combine these and then insert this variable into my code. But anything else I put as a replacement of `first_name` only errors.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :submitter_id, Building.order(:name), :submitters, :name, :id, :first_name, :prompt => "Select name"%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by simply making a method in your model.

In your model (Building or Submitter?), add the following:

```
def full_name
  self.first_name + self.last_name
end
```

then use this method in the grouped collection helper method like:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :submitter_id, Building.order(:name), :submitters, :name, :id, :full_name, :prompt => "Select name"%>
```

Comment: I was just typing up the same full_name method.

Comment: Damn! I was so close! Didn't have `self.`. Thanks!